# iMac 27", Mid 2010 (11,3 model)

Tags: memory

I have an iMac 27", Mid 2010 (11,3 model), "Core i7" 2.93 GHz. 4*2GB installed RAM..Plan to upgrade. 
Any thoughts, experience if 4 * 8 GB would work if upgraded to or is 16GB with 4*4GB max I can reach?
Thank you

Comment: Mactracker app is useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i7-2.93-27-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html), the answer is a maximum of `4x8GB=32GB`.

[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/imac-%2827-inch%2C-mid-2010%29-imac11%2C3#MEMORYFilters) will sell you 2x8GB for $103.99.

[OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/upgrades/imac-27-inch-mid-2010-2.93-ghz/memory) will sell you 1x8GB for $39.99 or 4x8GB for $159.99.

Comment: it is i7. And below is sytem report of memory.. So I assume it can go up to 32GB... Any comment? Tnks
  Model Name: iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac11,3
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2,93 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory: 8 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 97.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 1.59f2

Comment: So, if you check Mactracker, then 32GB, but Apple says a maximum of 16GB - always Apple gives a lower limit.

Comment: Sometimes the larger memory does not exist at the time computer is manufactured. When a larger size becomes available Apple does not update its documentation. Apple has solved this problem by not letting you add memory in many of the latest models.